# Image spaces of polynomial maps

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, quadratics

Suppose we have a map $L$ from $\Bbb{F}^n$ to $\Bbb{F}^m$ ($\Bbb{F}$ is an algebraically closed field) where each coordinate of $L(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a homogeneous linear form in $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Then we know that $\operatorname{Im}(L)$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb{F}^m$, because the image space is closed under scaling by a field constant and closed under addition.

Now suppose instead of homogeneous linear forms, the coordinates of the output were homogeneous degree 2 (or degree $t$) polynomials in the input variables (or more generally, homogeneous degree $t$ polynomials). That is, $L(\vec{x}) = (L_1(\vec{x}), \dots, L_m(\vec{x}))$, where $L_i$ are homogeneous degree 2 polynomials. The image space is still closed under scaling by a field constant. It isn't clear that the sum of two vectors from the image space will still be in image space.

*Is there some other such condition that's true now?*

Maybe some polynomial $f$ (dependent on the degree of the polynomials $L_i$ that generate the output coordinates, but independent of the specific polynomials) such that  "for every $k$ vectors $u_1, \dots, u_k$ in $\operatorname{Im}(L)$, $f(u_1, \dots, u_k)$ is also in $\operatorname{Im}(L)$"? For instance, when we were working with linear forms, $k=2$ and $f(u,v) = u+v$.

Comment: The image is not even necessarily closed under scalar multiplication if your field is not algebraically closed, just consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chevalley%27s+theorem+on+constructible+sets

Comment: @SergeyGuminov ah I hadn't realised that! Thanks, will edit appropriately

Comment: @KentaS Thanks, I'll check this out. I've been learning algebraic geometry on a need-to-know basis (for algebraic complexity theory). Do you know that this answers my question for sure, or is it something that could potentially help?